# Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 in console

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

this is the contents of a file named menu.json:

```
 { "name":"John", "city":"New York"}
```

I want to use jquery to parse the json file into the console of Chrome

```
var res = $.getJSON("menu.json", function() {})

        .done(function() {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(res);
            console.log(obj.name);
        });
```

For some reason, Chrome is saying
"**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**"

I'm running the page in MAMP and in the network tab, I am able to see the json file that's been loaded correctly. Why is this error occurring. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `getJSON` parses the response before it is passed to the success callback.  You don't have to parse it.  Also `res` in your snippet is the promise returned from the getJSON call so that doesn't make sense that you are trying to parse that anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to decode an object, not a JSON string.

The thing you're trying to decode is being serialized before it gets passed to the JSON decoder as `[object Object]`, hence the `o` at index 1.

Go back to the [getJSON docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) and you'll see you're not setting up your callback correctly. The return value you're storing in `res` is not what you think it is. You need to collect an argument to your callback function -- this is where your decoded response will be.

This should get you on the right lines:

```
$.getJSON("menu.json")
.done(function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The data will already be parsed.  Just accept the response in as an input to the done callback.

```js
var url = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/taplar/taplar-hiddenworld/b69ca458/src/assets/jsons/potions.json'

$.getJSON(url).done(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```